# Need help in solving $10x-\frac1x=3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

Solve: $10x-\frac{1}{x}=3$

This is what I've tried:

After the first step,

$\frac{10x^2-1}{x}=3$

$\Rightarrow$ $10x^2-3x-1=0$

But, I am not able to factorize this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can always use the quadratic formula

Comment: $(5x+1)(2x-1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: by the quadradic formula we get $$x_{1,2}=\frac{3}{20}\pm \sqrt{\frac{9}{400}+\frac{40}{400}}$$

Comment: I don't know about the quadratic formula. Is there any other way to solve the sum or can you explain me the quadratic formula, sir?

Comment: see here http://www.purplemath.com/modules/quadform.htm

Comment: quadratic formula :
$$x=\frac{-b+-\sqrt(b^2-4ac)}{2a}$$
for standard form of quadratic equation
$$ax^2+bx+c=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy way of solving $10x^2-3x-1=0$.

What we would like to do is to turn $10x^2$ into a perfect square, but just multiplying both side of the equation by $10$ will leave fractions later on (which I would like to avoid). So, instead, I'm going to multiply by $2^2\cdot10 = 40$

$$40(10x^2-3x-1)=40\cdot0$$
$$400x^2-3(40)x-40=0$$
$$20^2x^2-6(20)x-40=0$$
$$(20x)^2-6(20x)-40=0$$
let $t=20x$
$$t^2-6t-40=0$$
$$(t-10)(t+4)=0$$
$$(20x-10)(20x+4)=0$$
$$\dots$$